# how do I deal: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have built GPU instance on google cloud compute engine two weeks ago. When I reconnect today, it says:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Instance [nndial-1] in zone [asia-east1-b] has not been allocated an external IP address yet. Try rerunning this command later.

I tried several times, but still can't use.

I have allocated an external IP last time, why it does relate with the zone?

Comment: I assume you've allocated an external IP address from VPC Network > External IP addresses to the GCE instance. Does it say that it is in use by instance 'nndial-1'?

Comment: thanks for your answering, I know what's the problem with me

Comment: You've managed to resolve the issue? Would you mind telling how?

Comment: 'nndial-1' is another instance, I make mistake with the name. The problem is I wanted to connect one instance without external IP addresses and which is not running. But the prompt is not accurate.

Comment: @andy Would you be able to post this comment as an answer for the benefit of the community? This is in case another member faces the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is that the user has simply failed to start the VM instance from within the Compute Engine console on GCP.  To make sure that the instance is actually running, logon to your GCP console, then select `VM instances` under `Compute Engine` on the left-hand tab of the GCP console.  If your instance is running, you will see a green check mark.

If the instance is not running, you can click on the vertical ellipsis at the far right side of the instance's data table and click `Start` to start the VM.

Answer (score 0):

'nndial-1' is another instance, I make mistake with the name. The problem is I wanted to connect one instance without external IP addresses and which is not running. But the prompt is not accurate.